# SQL related , Get latest related record

Tags: sql, linq

say this is my records

```
Favid MerchantId       CustomerId                  Reason   CreatedTime
1     58    7A4BB789-DC5B-430C-8321-A168AFE0C589        2012-02-10 16:48:28.087
2     58    7A4BB789-DC5B-430C-8321-A168AFE0C589    bbx 2012-02-11 21:00:00.903
3     58    7A4BB789-DC5B-430C-8321-A168AFE0C589    bbx 2012-02-12 21:02:25.357
4     58    7A4BB789-DC5B-430C-8321-A168AFE0C589    bbx 2012-02-13 21:04:48.123
5     58    7A4BB789-DC5B-430C-8321-A168AFE0C589    bbx 2012-02-13 21:15:06.717
6     58    7A4BB789-DC5B-430C-8321-A168AFE0C589    lol 2012-02-13 21:38:24.703
7     58    7A4BB789-DC5B-430C-8321-A168AFE0C589    cf  2012-02-13 21:45:25.303
8     59    7A4BB789-DC5B-430C-8321-A168AFE0C589    halo    2012-02-13 21:49:23.273
9     58    7A4BB789-DC5B-430C-8321-A168AFE0C589    bya 2012-02-17 21:54:06.337
10    59    CBDD557F-0DF2-4455-82FC-18C473A4044A    good    2012-02-14 15:17:54.197
11    59    CBDD557F-0DF2-4455-82FC-18C473A4044A    lala    2012-02-16 15:36:39.240
12    59    CBDD557F-0DF2-4455-82FC-18C473A4044A    tatar   2012-02-13 15:40:56.907
13    59    CBDD557F-0DF2-4455-82FC-18C473A4044A    heh 2012-02-13 15:46:24.417
14    58    CBDD557F-0DF2-4455-82FC-18C473A4044A    lahaha  2012-02-24 15:50:48.450
```

For example , I want to get a count for the latest distinct CustomerID that had matching MerchantId number 58 , but **the tricky part here is the particular CustomerId might already have a later matching MerchantId 59 , so I would like to omit this count .**

So , what could the query be ? Thanks .

Comment: Did you want the SQL or LINQ statement?

Comment: So, what would be your expected result given the previous example?

Comment: anything sql or linq would do . Result should be a count of 2 , given the target merchantID is 58 .

Let say record Favid 9 , the merchantId is 59 , the count should be 1 , given the target merchantId is 58 .

Comment: context.fc_Favorites
                                                .GroupBy( e=> e.CustomerId).Distinct()
                                                .Where( e => e.MerchantId == merchantId)

something like this ? but i couldnt get the code corect

Comment: Ok how do I get a distinct customerID record of the table above with linQ ?

Answer (score 0):

I would start with:

```
select count(distinct customerID) from details d, customers c 
where d.merchant_id = 58 and 
(select count(*) from details d2 where c2.customerID = d2.customerid) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want the number of distinct CustomerID values for which 58 appears as the MerchantID in the most recent row for that customer? In the query below, the most recent row for each customer is identified because it has 1 for the value of rank() over (partition by CustomerID order by CreatedTime desc). Such rows are counted if they have MerchantID = 58.

```
declare @target int = 58;
with RankedPerCustomerID as (
  select
    CustomerID,
    MerchantID,
    rank() over (
      partition by CustomerID
      order by CreatedTime desc
    ) as rk
  from Fav
)
  select
    count(*) as numCustomers
    from RankedPerCustomerID
    where rk = 1 and MerchantID = @target;
```

Answer (score 0):

The inner query partitions (groups) the data by customerId and rownumbers the results (starting from 1) ordered within each partition by CreatedTime.

For your sample data, this row would be given a row number of 1 (within customer **7A4BB789-DC5B-430C-8321-A168AFE0C589**)

```
9     58    7A4BB789-DC5B-430C-8321-A168AFE0C589    bya 2012-02-17 21:54:06.337
```

The outer query then looks only within the "latest record per customer" and picks out where the last merchant associated with each customer is 58.

```
select count(*)
from
(
select *, rn=row_number() over (partition by CustomerId order by CreatedTime desc)
from Tbl
) Innr
where rn=1
  and MerchantId = 58
```

And `COUNT`s it, of course, for the result.  Now if you wanted other information, such as CustomerIds, then just change COUNT(*) in the select expression to something more meaningful.